# Scala generic case class with optional field

Tags: scala, generics

I have the following generic case class to model a resources in an HTTP API (we use Akka HTTP):

```scala
case class Job[Result](
   id: String,
   result: Option[Result] = None,
   userId: String,
)
```

and want to specify multiple, named, variations of a `Job`, were some of them provide a result, while others don't:

```scala
case class FooResult(data: String)
type FooJob = Job[FooResult]

// BarJob does not have any result, thus result should be None
case class BarJob = Job[/*what do to?*/]
```

my question is, is there any way to define `Job` as a generic case class where the type parameter only needs to be specified when the field `result` is `Some` ?  What I would like to do is something like:

```scala
// result is by default None in Job, so I don't want to specify any type here
case class BarJob = Job
```

Or perhaps there's better ways to do this, rather than using type aliases?

Comment: Is `(j: Job[FooResult]).result.isEmpty` a possible scenario, or are all `Job[FooResult]`s supposed to be always non-empty? In that case, having an `Option` there seems unnecessary in the first place.

Comment: That's a good point, it's not a possible scenario, so agree that Option is unnecessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use base `trait`s for `Job`s with and without results:

```
trait Job {
  def id: String
  def userId: String
}

trait JobWithResult[T] extends Job {
  def result: T
}

case class FooResult(data: String)
case class FooJob(id: String, userId: String, result: FooResult) extends JobWithResult[FooResult]

case class BarJob(id: String, userId: String) extends Job
```

You can then use `match` on a `Job` to see whether it has a result or not.

```
job match {
  case FooJob(id, userId, foo) => println(s"FooJob with result $foo")
  case j: JobWithResult[_] => println(s"Other job with id ${j.id} with result")
  case j: Job => println(s"Job with id {$j.id} without result")
}
```

This assumes that the `result` is not actually optional.

Comment: In reality, the `Job` has ~10 more fields, so I was hoping that I would not have to repeat them for each job, but this still seems like the best solution I can think of.

Comment: @simen-andresen you may use composition instead of inheritance and have a case class only for the `Result` fields and other that has a `Result` and a `Job`

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, the `Option` is "unnecessary".

I submit, it's not so much "unnecessary" as *indicative* ... of a way for you to implement what you want without repetitive declarations.

```
  case class Job[Result](id: String, userId: String, result: Option[Result] = None)

  object Job { 
      def void(id: String, userId: String) = Job[Nothing](id, userId)
      def apply[R](id: String, userId: String, result: R) = Job(id, userId, Option(result))
   }

   type FooJob = Job[FooResult]
   type VoidJob = Job[Nothing]
```